# Any simple python module documentation generator that does not try to run/import code?

Tags: python

I have a pretty large project with lot of packages, modules and dependencies. I want to generate the API doc of a few modules in the project. The documentation is already added as doc-strings.

I tried using sphinx but I am plagued with import errors. And the configuration required to avoid these import errors is just too much for my need.

Is there a doc generator that would take a module, parse the doc strings in it and produce the output, either in markdown, rst or html in a good readable format?

Comment: What other doc generators did you try?

Comment: I also tried pdoc... which comes pretty close. But it also tries to import the module

Answer (score 1):

Epydoc:

> --parse-only, --introspect-only   By default, epydoc will gather information about each Python object using two methods: parsing the
>   object's source code; and importing the object and directly
>   introspecting it. Epydoc combines the information obtained from these
>   two methods to provide more complete and accurate documentation.
>   However, if you wish, you can tell epydoc to use only one or the other
>   of these methods. For example, if you are running epydoc on untrusted
>   code, you should use the --parse-only option.

Comment: Does epydoc support python3?

Comment: Scratch that.. even if python3 is supported, epydoc doesnt work for me... :(

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to mock the not wanted modules (see also: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889621/sphinx-how-to-exclude-imports-in-automodule)). Epydoc was no solution for me and has not been maintained for long time. I'm not sure if it is too much configuration required for your needs, but imho a very straightforward solution.

```
import mock

MOCK_MODULES = ['numpy', 'matplotlib', ...]
for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES:
    sys.modules[mod_name] = mock.Mock()
```

Comment: I saw this... too many modules (both user created and otherwise). Would this go in the actual source files or in the sphinx conf file??

Comment: Hey, afaik at the top of your conf.py. You should take a look at the following [post](http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-make-your-sphinx-documentation-compile-with-readthedocs-when-youre-using-numpy-and-scipy/) or this [so-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889621/sphinx-how-to-exclude-imports-in-automodule). Hope this helps..

Comment: Tried doing that... like I said too many imports. For example, there is a model class that uses mongoengine. Now I have to add all the mongo engine field classes to MOCK_MODULES and I dont even want to generate doc for models.py. The reason I dont want to use sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

[pdoc](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc), but it imports the modules it documents and parses [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s only in case of `__init__()` method to discover instance variables.

If you are plagued with import errors, you may be doing something wrong. A common idiom in Python is to wrap any module-level code that is not to be executed when the module is simply imported behind this if-guard:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This will only be run when the module is run,
    # but not when it is imported
    ...
```

See also: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)