# Check if Sphinx doc called the script

Tags: python, python-sphinx, arcpy

I am currently trying to generate sphinx documentation for scripts which use the ArcGIS arcpy library.

I am running into an issue when sphinx tries to run the scripts while generating the documentation, as arcpy scripts take input parameters from the arcgis gui. Since sphinx is calling the scripts without the gui, these parameters are empty and are causing Tracebacks such as:

```
C:\VersionControl\PythonScripts\Source\src\_build\script_export_pdf.rst:4: WARNING:     autodoc: failed to import module u'gis.scripts.script_export_pdf'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\VersionControl\PythonScripts\Source\src\lib\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc.py", line 335, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "C:\VersionControl\PythonScripts\Source\src\gis\scripts\script_export_pdf.py", line 76, in <module>
    mxd.ExportToPDF(in_mxds, out_folder, overwrite, current)
  File "C:\VersionControl\PythonScripts\Source\src\gis\mapping\mxd.py", line 315, in ExportToPDF
    _ExportToPDF(arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(m), out_folder, overwrite)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 609, in __init__
    assert (os.path.isfile(mxd) or (mxd.lower() == "current")), gp.getIDMessage(89004, "Invalid MXD filename")
AssertionError: Invalid MXD filename.
```

I get around this issue in unittests by setting a variable when the test begins which the script checks for and sets test values in the parameters, I am wondering if there is a similar workaround with sphinx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I came up with, while probably no-where near ideal, is to simply check

```
if 'sphinx' in sys.modules:
    in_mxds = [r"C:/test.mxd"]
else:
    in_mxds = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
```

This will ensure the script is not trying to get a parameter from the GUI which isn't set when generating sphinx documents.

Comment: An excellent hack for most projects!  Unfortunately, if you're documenting a sphinx extension, it won't work :/

Answer (score 4):

I do something like this.  In my `conf.py` I add a new variable to the `builtins` module like:

```py
# anywhere in conf.py before any of your modules are imported
import builtins
builtins.__sphinx_build__ = True
```

Then in my module code I can write a check like:

```py
try:
    from some_dependency import SomeClass
except ImportError:
    try:
        if __sphinx_build__:
            class SomeClass:
                """Mock the class"""
    except NameError:
        raise ImportError('some_dependency')
```

Comment: In a similar spirit, it's possible to set an environment variable like `os.environ['SPHINX_BUILD'] = '1'` (suggested by GitHub copilot...)

Answer (score 2):

If your project is importing `sphinx` (in my case a sphinx extension), the following may also work for you

```
import os
import sys
if os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]) == "sphinx-build":
    # code for when sphinx is running
else:
    # code for regular application
```

I'm not sure if that will work on Windows or if it should be something like

```
if os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]) in ["sphinx-build", "sphinx-build.exe"]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Sphinx 1.3 there is a simple solution for this issue. Just add

```
autodoc_mock_imports = ['arcpy']
```

to your *conf.py*. This can be used when some external dependencies are not met at build time and break the building process.
See [Sphinx: how to exclude imports in automodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889621/sphinx-how-to-exclude-imports-in-automodule).

It's unfortunate that Esri has very poor arcpy documentation and mostly ignores Python standards.