# Class path in Sphinx generated documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I would like to expose some classes to `__init__.py` of package (for user convenience) but I would like to keep its implementation in sub package. 
Sphinx properly generate its documentation as elements from `__init__` but when documenting inheriting class it show original file, not `__init__`. If there is way to change its?

How it works:

[image]

What I wont:

[image]

MWE:

```
├── docs
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── package.rst
│   └── _static
└── package
    ├── base_class.py
    ├── inherit_class.py
    └── __init__.py
```

`__init__.py`

```py
from .base_class import A

__all__ = ("A",)
```

`base_class.py`

```py
class A:
    def test(self):
        pass
```

`inherit_class.py`

```py
from .base_class import A

class B(A):
    def test2(self):
        pass
```

package.rst

```
package package
===============

Submodules
----------

package.inherit\_class module
-----------------------------

.. automodule:: package.inherit_class
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:


Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: package
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

index.rst

```
package
=======

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   package
```

conf.py

```py
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/config

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'Test'
copyright = '2019, Grzegorz Bokota'
author = 'Grzegorz Bokota'

# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '0.1'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = ["sphinx.ext.autodoc"
]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'alabaster'

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']

master_doc = "index"
```

Comment: This looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/47903710/407651. Try adding `A.__module__ = "package"` in base_class.py.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion. This response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843737/check-if-sphinx-doc-called-the-script and such code:

```python
if os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]) in ["sphinx-build", "sphinx-build.exe"]:
    for el in __all__:
        globals()[el].__module__ = __name__
```
do a job