# unittest mock and multiple inheritance: TypeError: metaclass conflict

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I have a package that has a dependency that is not `pip` installable. In order to be able to build the documentation, I am trying to mock the non-installable package using [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock).

However I stumbled across a problem with multiple inheritance: when one of the parent classes is a mock class I get:

> TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses

The following example illustrates the issue:

**file: class_a.py**

```
class A:
    pass
```

**file: code.py**

```
from class_a import A

class B:
    pass

class C(A, B):
    pass
```

**file: test.py**

```
import sys
from unittest import mock

# inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/37363830/1860757
MOCK_MODULES = ['class_a', ]
sys.modules.update((mod_name, mock.MagicMock()) for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES)

import code

code.C()
```

If I run `python3 test.py` I get the above exception.
If I comment the line starting with `sys.modules.update`, it all behaves as expected.

Is there a way to mock modules or classes such that multiple inheritance continue working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some more research and tests and I have found a way, so I answer my own question for completeness. I don't know if it is a solution or a workaround. However the trick is to **explicitly** mock classes involved in multiple inheritance. The following does work as expected:

```
import sys
from unittest import mock


class _A:
    pass

MOCK_MODULES = ['class_a', ]
sys.modules.update((mod_name, mock.MagicMock()) for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES)
patcher = mock.patch('class_a.A', new=_A)
patcher.start()


import code


code.C()

patcher.stop()
```

---

If anyone in the future finds a new/better way, ping me and I will re-evaluate the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is and old post but anyway.
Looks like these lines are not necessary because the module class_a exists you don't need to mock it:

```
# MOCK_MODULES = ['class_a', ]
# sys.modules.update((mod_name, mock.MagicMock()) for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES)
```