# Sphinx Python: create documentation where python script imports a module I don't have installed

Tags: python, cron, python-sphinx

Is it possible to create a documentation in Sphinx (Python), where one of the python scripts imports a module (in this case `python-crontab` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab)) that I don't have installed?

```
from crontab import CronTab
```

Basically I am writing the documentation on a Windows machine. The code works fine, but not on a Windows machine since crontab is only for Linux. Thus, I was wondering if there is a way in Sphinx to tell it that it doesn't matter if it cannot find `crontab`

Comment: I think it should work if you mock `crontab`. Add `autodoc_mock_imports = ["crontab"]` in conf.py. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15912502/407651.